# Three JS Shadow from tree not cast

Tags: three.js, webgl

Learning Three Js by my own and with some (incredible) stuff found on Internet, I use Script to generate a LowPoly Planet, but trees does not cast Shadow on the ground.

I look for help but didn't find something to work. Can you explain me why please ?

I tried many things with MeshLambertMaterial and things like :

```
mesh.castShadow = true; mesh.receiveShadow = true; etc..
```

Here is a fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/Fliip36/fcz2psuj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trees are objects, that consist of several meshes (as they are `Object3D` or `Group`), so to make them to cast shadows, you need to use `.traverse()` method.

So change this part

```js
objects.push(obj);
obj.scale.set(0.01, 0.01, 0.01);
obj.tween = TweenMax.to(obj.scale, rnd(3, 10), { x: 1, y: 1, z: 1, ease: Elastic.easeOut.config(1, 0.2), delay: rnd(0, 4) });
obj.receiveShadow = true;
obj.castShadow = true;
planet.add(obj);
```

to this:

```js
objects.push(obj);
obj.scale.set(0.01, 0.01, 0.01);
obj.tween = TweenMax.to(obj.scale, rnd(3, 10), { x: 1, y: 1, z: 1, ease: Elastic.easeOut.config(1, 0.2), delay: rnd(0, 4) });
obj.traverse(o => {
    if (o.isMesh){ // set these parameters for meshes only
        o.receiveShadow = true;
        o.castShadow = true;
    }
})
planet.add(obj);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation and solution ! I'll check Traverse to learn more